# How to lock shared_mutex from one function and unlock it from other function?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, std, c++17

I have a class which has several readers and several writers.
I want to use read/write lock (using `shared_mutex`)

All the examples and information about this lock, use and release the lock in the same function:
[std::shared_mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex)

I want to use (for reason I wan't explain here) `shared_mutex` in this way:

```
Lock4Read();
UnLock4Read();
Lock4Write();
UnLock4Write();
```

So I can lock the object I need, do my logic, and release it at the end (in other function).

How can I do it ?

I know I can do it using linux `pthread_rwlock_rdlock`, but can I do it using `shared_mutex`  ?

Comment: just share the mutex in your class and call `lock` for `lock4write` and `lock_shared` for `lock4read` in your apis.

Comment: but after exiting the function, the locks will be released (and I want to release it manually)

Comment: No, it's not.  Until you don't use `std::unique_lock` or unlock it by yourself.

Comment: They will be released only if you wrap `shared_mutex` in  `std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex>` Look at constructor and destructor of unique_lock. You have to not used `unique_lock` and use shared_mutex and make sure to call lock and unlock at right time. easy enough to shoot yourself in foot.

Comment: *"All the examples and information about this lock, use and release the lock in the same function:"* As it is generally safer/simpler to use RAII for that: You cannot forget to `unlock`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't pretty sure that you want to do something like that, but check this, maybe it will be helpful for you :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <shared_mutex>
#include <thread>

class ThreadMom {
 public:
  void Lock4Read() { mutex_.lock_shared(); }
  void UnLock4Read() { mutex_.unlock_shared(); }
  void Lock4Write() { mutex_.lock(); }
  void UnLock4Write() { mutex_.unlock(); }
 private:
  std::shared_mutex mutex_;
};

template <typename T> class Value {
 public:
  T get() const {return value_;}
  void set(const T& value) {value_ = value;}
 private:
  T value_;
};

int main() {
  ThreadMom mom;
  Value<int> value;
  value.set(0);
  auto increment_and_print = [&mom, &value](int which) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      mom.Lock4Write();
      value.set(i * which);
      mom.UnLock4Write();
      mom.Lock4Read();
      std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << ' ' << value.get() << '\n';
      mom.UnLock4Read();
    }
  };

  std::thread thread1(increment_and_print, 1);
  std::thread thread2(increment_and_print, 2);

  thread1.join();
  thread2.join();
}
```

Comment: I've done it like it is done on cppreference. And it seems that it works when I tested it,

Comment: No, I don't think so this methods have the same implementation. I don't use `Lock4Read`/`UnLock4Read`, because it is easy to add it, but it will be make example a little much bigger. If you will check this once more time you can say that maybe there should be some comments and maybe some constructors in these classes. It is minimal example. If you have better idea how it should be done, then provide it here, please :)